# Responsive Web Page Scrolling Glitch On iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, responsive-design, semantic-ui

I created simple web page using semantic ui library: http://cvhunter.net/m

Scrolling vertically is glitching on iphone sometimes especially first scrolling try.

How can i fix this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem, it is causing because of overflow-x:hidden at container div.